# JdbcSQLException when using SQL Security Invoker in In MySql with Intellij and H2?

Tags: mysql, sql, intellij-idea, h2

I have some scripts that are creating views using the SQL Security Invoker options.

The code script looks like this:

```
CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW viewOne AS
SELECT
    m1.id,
    sio.source as finalStep
FROM stepIO sio JOIN step s ON(sio.step_id=s.id) JOIN 
medium m1 ON(m1.version=s.model_id) JOIN coefficient c 
ON(c.id=m1.id)
WHERE sio.direction='O' AND sio.source NOT IN (
SELECT
  idref
FROM stepIO sio JOIN step s ON(sio.step_id=s.id) JOIN 
medium m ON(m.version=s.model_id) JOIN coefficient c 
ON(c.id=m.id)
    WHERE c.belongs_to_container_id=1 and m1.model_name=m.model_name) AND 
c.belongs_to_container_id=1;
```

When I run my tests in Intellij, I get this error.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "

CREATE SQL[*] SECURITY INVOKER VIEW viewOne AS
//
//
c.belongs_to_container_id=1; "expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX";
```

It seems like it's rejecting the `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` as incorrect SQL syntax. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is one database and H2 is another database.

The syntax of the SQL is different on both of them.

There's no such thing as `CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW ...` in H2. See [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_view).